# Show that a singleton $\{x\}$ is negligible

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

With the following definition of negligible set :

$S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is negligible if $$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \hspace{0.2cm} \exists I_{k} : S \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}}I_{k} \hspace{0.2cm}, \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}} |I_{k}| < \varepsilon$$

With $I_{k}$ closed or open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$.

I'd like to prove that a singleton $\{x\}$ is negligible, to be able to say for example that $\mathbb{Q}$ is negligible.

This was my effort :trying with the definition,noticing that $\{x\} \subseteq (x-\frac{1}{k},x+\frac{1}{k}) = |I_{k}|,$

I thought that those could be my interval because $|I_{k}| = \frac{2}{k} \underset{k \to \infty}{\longmapsto} 0$, therefore they satisfy $|I_{k}| < \varepsilon$,

But then i realized i was wrong because i had to sum all the lengths of the intervals,but $\sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{k} = +\infty$, is that right ?

If so,any solution or tip to solve the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using $\frac{\delta}{2^k}$ in place of $\frac{1}{k}$, and pick $\delta$ such that the sum is less than $\epsilon$

Comment: Pick $I_1:= \left(x-\frac{\epsilon}{2}, x+ \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right)$, then let $I_k = \emptyset$ for $k \geq 2$.

Comment: Do you mean $\forall \epsilon \exists I_k ...$? As it stands, $\epsilon$ and $I_k$ are unbound variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why summing them? For each $\varepsilon>0$, take $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac2k<\varepsilon$ and take only the interval $\left(x-\frac1k,x+\frac1k\right)$. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply are required to have your $k$s be a *subset* of $\mathbb N$, then you can take $k=1$,  $(x-\frac 1 {3 \epsilon},x+\frac 1 {3 \epsilon}$. If you have to have $I_k$ for every natural number, take  $(x-\frac 1 {2^{k+3} \epsilon},x+\frac 1 {2^{k+3} \epsilon})$.